# How to make Hamburger button return to original state once another link in the off canvas menu has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, hamburger-menu

Right, so I am making myself a website with html, css and js. I have created an off canvas menu that opens and closes with a toggleMenu function I created in js and works perfectly. The problem is when I get off this menu by clicking the about link. The menu closes like it should but the hamburger button does not revert back to it's orginal state. Is there a way I can code this as I have been trying to figure this out but have had no success.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

var toggleStatus = 1;

function toggleMenu() {
  if (toggleStatus === 1) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
    toggleStatus = 0;
  } else if (toggleStatus === 0) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    toggleStatus = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

#Header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#Header h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #Header h2 {
    display: block;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

.lineContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
}

.lineContainer:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 8px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 7px;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 7px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-9px, -7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-9px, -7px);
}


/* Side Nav menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #942dad;
  /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px;
  /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.about {
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .lineContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 55px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!---Animated 3 line menu icon-->
  <button class="lineContainer" onclick="toggleMenu(), myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
     </button>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a class="about" href="#about" onclick="toggleMenu()">About</a>
    <a href="#m">Meet Me</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Form</a>
    <a href="#">Reviews</a>
    <a href="#">Social Media</a>
  </div>


  <div id="main">
    <div id="Header">
      <h2>Learning</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <h2>About?</h2>
      <p>[TEXT GOES HERE] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ante est, faucibus non fermentum nec, sollicitudin eu mi. Nulla eu ex metus. Praesent convallis purus eget molestie laoreet. Pellentesque id ante eu ante ullamcorper
        eleifend at nec nisi. Curabitur rhoncus efficitur est, nec viverra mauris fermentum et. Suspendisse efficitur, mi vel sagittis vulputate, purus orci semper dui, molestie ornare erat mauris non lectus. Duis lacus lorem, gravida non erat non, ultrices
        facilisis justo. Nunc aliquam elit sed elit eleifend laoreet. In a efficitur orci. Sed ornare, ante a convallis sollicitudin, ipsum est sollicitudin elit, et iaculis eros urna nec tortor. Suspendisse placerat metus imperdiet est aliquam, at condimentum
        sapien facilisis. Vestibulum consectetur interdum nisi et congue. Mauris pretium eget augue nec sodales. Vestibulum volutpat a justo ac imperdiet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` attached to the "About" link doesn't call `myFunction()`

On a related note, you could replace a lot of that javascript by just toggling a class on the `<body>`, then using CSS to affect the visibility of the menu.

```js
document.querySelector(".toggler").addEventListener("click",()=>{  
  document.body.classList.toggle("nav-open");
});
```

```css
.sideNav {
  width: 250px;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  transition: transform 200ms;
  background: purple;
}

.nav-open .sideNav {
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="toggler">Toggle</button>
  <div class="sideNav">
    This is sidenav
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```